# TweetStream Setup on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Hey guys got a quick question here, how do i set up TweetStream after i install the gem? I looked at the Doc it looks straight foward just a few lines of code but im not quite sure where it goes and how to set it up initially,  is there a sample code any where where i can see the full process of incorporating this gem? Thnx in advance for newbie questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the gem, but if I'm reading it correctly, you should be able to do a pretty basic setup by adding the following code to a controller:

```
def index
  @tweets = []
  TweetStream::Client.new(:username => 'you', :password => 'pass').userstream do |status|
    @tweets << status.text
  end
end
```

Then in the view just do something like:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <p><%= tweet %></p>
<% end %>
```

Make sure you have the TweetStream gem in your Gemfile

```
gem 'tweetstream'
```

After you run `bundle install` and launch the server, you should be good to go.

Comment: thnx alot ill let you know how that goes!

Comment: Updated my answer, realized the example view code wasn't showing up.